# NoneType object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, pyserial

I have a Python program which opens serial port COM4 to send a few commands. I am modifying it in such a way that while serial port COM4 is open, I want to open serial port COM5 for sometime and send a few commands. I have a pyserial object called serialChannel which does all the operations for port COM4 and it works as expected. I created another Pyserial object serialChannel5 (declared just below serialChannel object in the file comms.py under class comms) as in:

```
 # Constructor
    def __init__(self):
        # Class attributes
        self.serialChannel = None  #Pyserial obj
        self.serialChannel5 = None
        self.command = None
        self.loggingOn = False
        self.device = None
```

This is what my program does:

```
def myscr(control, log):
    mycomms = comms.comms()
    comms.serialOpen(logging=False)
    control.snd_rcv(defines.command1)
    comms.serialClose()
```

And this is the program which fails:

```
def myscr(control, log):
    mycomms = comms.comms()
    comms.serialOpen5(logging=False)
    control.snd_rcv5(defines.command1)
    comms.serialClose5()
```

If I just use my original functions, the command "command1" is sent on port 4 without a problem. But if I use port 5 related functions (function names suffixed by 5 at the end as above - like serialOpen5, snd_rcv5 etc), the program throws an error:

> NoneType object has no attribute write

These are my related functions for serial COM4. Pls note all functions for serial 5 are just replicated as these:

```
def serialOpen(self, port=None, logging=None):
    iport.device = COM4
    self.device = iport.device

    self.serialChannel = serial.Serial(
            port=self.device,
            baudrate=self.DEFAULT_BAUD,
            parity=self.DEFAULT_PARITY,
            stopbits=self.DEFAULT_STOPBITS,
            bytesize=self.DEFAULT_DATABITS,
            timeout=self.READ_TIMEOUT,
            write_timeout=self.WRITE_TIMEOUT
        )
        self.serialChannel.isOpen()
        self.serialChannel.flushInput()
        self.serialChannel.flushOutput()



def snd_rcv(self, cmd, logging=True,):
    try:
        res = self.comms.sndcmd(cmd)
        return res

def sndcmd(self, command)
    self.Tx(self.command)
    self.serialChannel.flushInput()

def Tx(self, cmd):
    self.serialChannel.write(cmd.encode())
    return True
```

The whole above sequence works for COM and sends command through COM4. When I replicate these functions for COM5, it throws an error:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'; (in sndcmd5)
>   sndcmd5 is COM5 equivalent to sndcmd

Code which throws the error:

```
def serialOpen5(self, port=None, logging=None):
    iport.device = COM5
    self.device = iport.device

    self.serialChannel5 = serial.Serial(
            port=self.device,
            baudrate=self.DEFAULT_BAUD,
            parity=self.DEFAULT_PARITY,
            stopbits=self.DEFAULT_STOPBITS,
            bytesize=self.DEFAULT_DATABITS,
            timeout=self.READ_TIMEOUT,
            write_timeout=self.WRITE_TIMEOUT
        )
        self.serialChannel5.isOpen()
        self.serialChannel5.flushInput()
        self.serialChannel5.flushOutput()



def snd_rcv5(self, cmd, logging=True,):
    try:
        res = self.comms.sndcmd5(cmd)
        return res

def sndcmd5(self, command)
    self.Tx5(self.command)
    self.serialChannel5.flushInput()

def Tx5(self, cmd):
    self.serialChannel5.write(cmd.encode())
    return True
```

Could some please help me find what am I doing wrong?

The script which has the function **myscr** is in the main script file. **def __init__** is in comms file along with functions **serialOpen/serialOpen5, sndcmd/sndcmd5, Tx/Tx5**.
**snd_rcv/snd_rcv5** is in another file named controller,

Comment: Always post **the whole error message** with **full traceback** please.

Comment: Why are you showing us only the working code, and not the code that *actually has the problem*?

Comment: @Selcuk - I'm sorry but my Pycharm just generates this error... I don't get more information as I have a bunch of try except statements..

Comment: @jasonharper - The code for COM5 is exactly the same (with a prefix of '5'). I am assuming I am doing something wrong with Pyserial object creation/passing?

Comment: @Selcuk - It also gives me the function name - which I have added it now to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me, I did not define the object control but used it in the main script. Fixed now by defining "control" in the script